# mapping newest messages first - React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, mapping, reverse

I'm trying to map my array of messages so that the newest message comes first.
I've tried a few ways but nothing seams to change, any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

```
const feedSort = [...feed].sort((a, b) => a.createdAt > b.createdAt);


{feedSort.map((data) =>
                   ......the data ......
)}
```

Comment: Can you provide more context, what is the type of createdAt field, if it is a string, which format of time?

Comment: createdAt: "2023-02-20T10:32:55.544Z"
it's taken from mongoDB

Comment: I think the issue is that you are effectively comparing date strings and javascript can produce unexpected results from that. it is better to make them Date objects and then compare them as that. Look answer bellow

Answer (score 0):

Try this after that map loop as you write.

```js
const feedSort = [...feed].sort((a, b) => b.createdAt - a.createdAt);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exact behavior when you subtract Date strings in javascript, but you should subtract them as Date objects like so:

```
const feedSort = [...feed].sort((a, b) => new Date(b.createdAt) - new Date(a.createdAt));
```